# Java - synchronization on non-final field

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

In the case of synchronizing on a field that can change its reference, as described below:

```
class A {

    Object someObject;

    void method(){
        synchronized (someObject) {
              Object newObject = new Object();
              //possibly modify the old ref
              if(chackCondition()){
                   someObject = newObject;
              }
        }
    }
}
```

I am worried that there might be some weird, low-level compiler optimization I am missing here that might let two threads access the synchronized area concurrently. Any comments would be greatly appreaciated.

Comment: Than why don't you use another object as a lock?

Comment: This is just for the example, something that got me thinking. I know I should use `ReenetrantLock` or indeed other lock object, but this is just for my understanding

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're absolutely right.  The moment `newObject` is exposed to other threads as the new value of `someObject`, those other threads are now using a completely different mutex, and so can be executing the "mutually exclusive" code concurrently.

A common solution is to just provide a different mutex and synchronize on that:

```
private final Object someObjectMutex = new Object();
```

Comment: Yes, but that is the last line of the code right, so I don't really care, as my thread will not perform any further operations in the mutex section, right?

Comment: @Bober02 You don't actually know that; without a common synchronization barrier, there's no *happens-before* between the threads, and in particular there's no requirement that instructions before that last assignment are actually executed before it is.

Comment: @Bober02 no imagine three threads, T1 has acquired someObject and T2 is waiting on someObject's lock to be available. Then T1 modifies someObject to newObject and T3 aqcuires newObject and enters the block. T1 releases someObject, allowing T2 to enter the block too. You now have two threads executing your block concurrently.

Comment: @assylias, thanks a lot for that, that was the example I needed :) stupid me, multithreading is much more complicated than it seems on the outside...

Comment: @assylias: Great counterexample!

Answer (score 1):

There's no optimization here. Two or several threads won't be synchronized at that point if `someObject` object reference is different for them. This is the reason why the object should be a `final` field. Also, if all threads using different instances of `A` must be synchronized at that point, mark the field as `static`.

Comment: `final` yes, `static` no.

Comment: `static` only if the lock has to be the same for all instances of the class, which is not the most common case

Answer (score 1):

Code snippet in the asked question shouldn't be called as synchronized as it is a bad practice of using non-final fields for locks/synchronized field.

**Good practice**: Use final objects for locking/synchronizing any critical section, this will help us avoiding any unintentional update on lock object.

As and when the object on which we are synchronizing our critical section of code get updated by new object, other threads would not be synchronized to the old object so all the threads which are working on old object will continue working in synchronized mode but other threads will not be synchronized as they are no longer sharing the same lock.

For better understanding, see below code:-

```
import java.util.Date;


public class SynchronizingNonFinalField {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SharedObject sharedObject = new SharedObject();
        MyIntendedThreadRunner runner = new MyIntendedThreadRunner(sharedObject);
        Thread myThread1 = new Thread(runner);
        Thread myThread2 = new Thread(runner);
        Thread myThread3 = new Thread(runner);
        Thread myThread4 = new Thread(runner);
        Thread myThread5 = new Thread(runner);
        Thread myThread6 = new Thread(runner);
        Thread myThread7 = new Thread(runner);
        myThread1.start();
        myThread2.start();
        myThread3.start();
        myThread4.start();
        myThread5.start();
        myThread6.start();
        runner.setSharedObject(new SharedObject());
        myThread7.start();
    }
}

class MyIntendedThreadRunner implements Runnable {
    private SharedObject sharedObject;
//    final private SharedObject sharedObject;

    public MyIntendedThreadRunner(SharedObject sharedObject) {
        this.sharedObject = sharedObject;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (sharedObject) {
            sharedObject.increment10mins();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Although this doesn't seem to be practical here, but if we have some complex requirement,
            // then a thread unconsciously changed the shared object, so we should mark it as final
            sharedObject = new SharedObject();
            System.out.println(sharedObject.getObj());
        }
    }

    public void setSharedObject(SharedObject sharedObject) {
        this.sharedObject = sharedObject;
    }
}

class SharedObject {
    private Date obj;

    public SharedObject() {
        this.obj = new Date();
    }

    public Date getObj() {
        return obj;
    }

    public void setObj(Date obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public void increment10mins() {
        obj.setTime(obj.getTime() + (10 * 60 * 1000));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to be worried for a *low-level compiler optimization* because it's just a programming error. Lock objects are like semaphores: they synchronize actions of threads looking at them, but if two drivers look at two distinct semaphores, they are not synchronized anymore.

I stated it's a programming error because you never want to change the semaphore. If you need to modfiy the field after getting the lock, chances are that you are in fact using the same object for two (or more) distinct purposes, and that's a design mistake (note that you don't modify **the object**, you change the value of **the field** - if the object itself were mutated there would be no problem).

BTW, take a look at the helpers in `java.util.concurrent`, like [`ReentrantLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html)